# How do I redirect the ouput of a program when it is executed via the START command and order the output

Tags: batch-file

I'd like to do something like:

```
start program1 ^>output
start program2 ^>output
```

and order the output so that the output is ordered. I don't care which output is first (program1's or program2's), but I'd like it to be a complete dump of that program's output.

Ideally, I'd like to run multiple programs in parallel with output all going to the screen, but a file would be fine. I don't need to see it while it is running, just have it intelligible when it's finished.

EDIT:

If I follow the suggestion to output them to a file then merge them when it's done, I have the trouble of waiting 'til all the programs are done -- so, I need a waitUntilAllTheStartsAreFinished command.

```
start program1 ^>output1
start program2 ^>output2
#... as many as I need
waitUntilAllTheStartsAreFinished 
TYPE output1
TYPE output2
delete output1
delete output2
```

Comment: You need to use different output file for each program and you need to wait until both programs finished their work. Then you can append any one output file onto another. Without the wait, it would be impossible to combine both output files.

Comment: It looks like I'll do it that way, just hoping there was a nice way to do exactly as I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joey's suggested method will work, but it can become problematic if your programs can be launched multiple times. It becomes difficult to tell which tasks are the onces you want to monitor.

Each program will have an exclusive lock on the temporary output file until the program finishes. Any attempt by another process to redirect to the same file will fail. This can be used to detect when the program finishes.

I used TIMEOUT to insert a delay in the polling. If you are on a system like XP that does not have TIMEOUT then you can use `ping -n 2 ::1 >nul 2>nul` instead.

I've included extensive documentation on how this solution works in the code. ***Edit*** - *I have simplified the code a bit by removing one unneccessary code block level, and I improved the documentation.*

```
@echo off
setlocal

REM Define a base name for the temporary output files. I've incorporated
REM a random number in the file name to generally make it safe to run this
REM master script multiple times simultaneously. It is unlikely a collision
REM will occur, but incorporating a timestamp in the name would make it more
REM reliable.
set "baseName=%temp%\output%random%_"
set /a "progCount=2, completedCount=0"

REM Start each program with both stdout and stderr redirected to a temporary
REM ouptut file. The program will have an exclusive lock on the output file
REM until it finishes executing. I've assumed the program is another batch file
REM and I use the START /B switch so that the programs are run in the same
REM window as this master script. Any console program will work, and the
REM /B switch is optional.
start /b "" ^"cmd /c test.bat ^>"%baseName%1" 2^>^&1^"
start /b "" ^"cmd /c test2.bat ^>"%baseName%2" 2^>^&1^"
REM etc.

REM Clear any existing completed flags, just in case
for /l %%N in (1 1 %progCount%) do set "completed%%N="

:loopUntilDone

REM Introduce a delay so we don't inundate the CPU while we poll
timeout /nobreak 1 >nul

REM Loop through each of the output file numbers.
REM Redirect the stderr for the DO block to nul so that if the inner
REM block redirection fails, the error message will be suppressed.
for /l %%N in (1 1 %progCount%) do (

  REM Only test this particular program if the output file has been
  REM created (in other words, the program has started) and we haven't
  REM already detected that it has finished. Also redirect an unused
  REM file handle to the output file in append mode.  The redirection will
  REM fail if the program has not completed. If the redirection fails then
  REM the IF block is not executed.
  if not defined completed%%N if exist "%baseName%%%N" (

      REM We are within the block, meaning the redirection succeeded and
      REM the program must have finished. So print out the results.
      echo(
      echo Ouput for program%%N
      echo ---------------------------------------------
      type "%baseName%%%N"

      REM Set a flag so we know this program has finished
      set completed%%N=1

      REM Increment the completed count so we know when we are done
      set /a completedCount+=1

  ) 9>>"%baseName%%%N"

) 2>nul

if %completedCount% neq %progCount% goto :loopUntilDone

del "%baseName%*"
```

Comment: Wow, this is great, it's exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a loop and `tasklist`:

```
:wait
rem just wait a second before looking again
ping -n 2 ::1 >nul 2>nul
tasklist 2>&1 | findstr /b "program1.exe program2.exe ..." >nul 2>&1 && goto wait
```

It will only continue further until all of `program1.exe program2.exe ...` are terminated.